# What is difference between "Merci" and "Merci beaucoup"?

Tags: sens, anglais, choix-de-mot

In english there is difference between thanks and thank you.

Is there a difference between merci and merci beaucoup ?
If yes .Is it about the person's age or the extent of my knowledge of the person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. "Merci" means "thanks / thank you" (there's no difference in French), and "merci beaucoup" means "thank you *very much*". "Beaucoup" is an adverb used to express a big quantity or intensity. With "merci beaucoup", you say that you are *very* thankful to whom you're speaking. It doesn't depend on how well you know the person, or their age or anything, only how thankful you are.

(I think "merci beaucoup" is a bit colloquial. I wouldn't use it in a formal letter. Other expressions would fit better, e.g. "un grand merci", roughly meaning "with great thanks".)